# Firebase Remote Config - How to write condition to target versions between two versions?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have a remote config in my android app and I only want to target it for app versions below and equal to Y and above and equal to X. So something like

```
Y >= version >=X
```

As per [this](https://firebase.blog/posts/2020/10/improved-version-targeting-in-remote) firebase blog post it says,

> Now it’s quick and easy to target versions of your app that came
> before, after, or exactly equal to a specific version number - no
> confusing regular expressions required! **So for example if you want
> to target a fix for users between specific versions of your app, like
> version numbers after 1.2.3 but before 1.3.4, it's as easy as setting
> these two conditions in the console: Version >= 1.2.3, and Version <
> 1.3.4.**

But the problem is that I do not see the option to set both these >= and <= conditions at the same time. Once I set one of the version conditions, I cannot select more version conditions since the version option is greyed out when I try to create a new condition. How do I write a condition to target versions between 2 versions? Thanks!